# How do I make if statement recognize grep as true or false?

Tags: bash, git, grep

I am currently trying to write a quick bash script to update all projects within a folder. I am trying to do it like so:

```
badCount=0
projectCount=0
manual_projects[badCount]="leave_empty"
badCount=$((badCount+1))

for project in */
do
    echo ''
    projectCount=$((projectCount+1))
    cd "$project"
    echo "$project"
    git fetch
    git checkout build | grep awudgawu
    if (git pull | grep -qw error); then
        manual_projects[$badCount]=$project
        badCount=$((badCount+1))
    fi
    cd ../
done
```

For some reason, it never goes in the if condition, even though there are projects that have an error being outputted from them. Why is my condition always resulting in false? And how can I make it return true if in the pull request, there is the word 'error'?

Comment: use bash -x to debug the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First of all

the issue you get comes from the fact the `| grep` sequence only looks at standard output (stdout), while the error message comes from standard error (stderr).

Toy example (do not try it as there's a `git rm…` !):

```sh
$ git rm '*'

$ git pull | grep Please
→ "doesn't work"

$ git pull 2>&1 | grep Please
→ Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

#### Next

the question is, are you really sure you want to rely on `grep`?

Because it seems like a tricky endeavor, to attempt to detect an error by doing `grep` on a the result of a git command. Indeed, it's not guaranteed that the `error` word itself will be part of the error message.

(Moreover, there is a subtlety related to the exit status of a pipe, e.g.,  `false | true ; echo $?`)

Actually, the so-called exit status (a.k.a. error code) can be used directly (`$?`), or with the help of an `if-then-else`.

Example:

```sh
$ false
$ echo $?
→ 1
$ true
$ echo $?
→ 0

$ if false; then echo ok; else echo ko; fi
→ ko

$ if git pull non-existing-remote; then
  echo ok
else
  echo ko
fi
```

#### Related tool

The script you attempt to create makes me think about the following tool developed by Joey Hess: http://myrepos.branchable.com (see also [this description](https://joeyh.name/blog/entry/introducing_mr/))

Disclaimer: I'm not a `myrepos` user myself, but I guess you might be interested in trying it as it was specifically devised to manage many repositories stored in a given folder…

Comment: Your link looks like what we are trying to do yeah, very good resources thanks. Not marking as answer as my focus is if I can pull, and get an error such as 'you need to commit your changes first', how can I interpret that with grep? (or any other way of doing it)

Comment: @NathanielCutajar OK (so I've extended my answer accordingly :)

Comment: Well done, that was a really detailed explanation. As you've pointed out, doing a `if(git pull)` resulted it in it checking if the output was good or not. Adding a `!` made it so when it fails, it goes in the if statement. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NathanielCutajar Don't use the parenthesis. `if (git pull)` is slower than `if git pull` because it spawns an extra subshell; that also means that if you're calling something like a shell function, it's prevented from setting variables in the parent shell, changing its working directory, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh I see. Any idea where having a subshell is actually useful?

Comment: @NathanielCutajar, sure; sometimes you _want_ to isolate a shell function to where it can change its own directory or override file descriptors without impacting the parent process. I also see people trying to use them for grouping sometimes, but in general curly braces make more sense in that context; `if { git pull; }; then` gets you the visual clarity without forcing the extra subshell.